# Connecting to SQL Server on AWS RDS from outside VPC

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an issue connecting to a new AWS RDS Sql Server instance from outside of the VPC.  This isn't new to me - I have a number of AWS database instances, but this one is completely stumping me.  As far as i can tell, I have mirrored settings between known working and this, confirmed DNS etc, but I cannot connect from either Azure DataStudio or my Dotnet App.

Here's what I have done so far...

Created an AWS RDS SQL Server Express instance, publicly available as follows:

[RDS Instance config with public YES.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLE9Y.jpg)

I have then configured the security policy, giving the EC2 instance subnet and my office IP access to the instance:

[Inbound rules on security policy attached to RDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItrNF.jpg)

I can then use SSMS from the EC2 instance to connect to the SQL Server without a problem:

[Connecting from SSMS on EC2 instance in the same VPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpYco.png)

However, if I then try to connect from Azure DataStudio on my Mac, I get an error:

[Azure DataStudio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MncBI.png)

If I inspect the error detail, I can see a full stack trace that does not on the face of it suggest anything more than a network error:

[Stack trace from Azure DataStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sDu9.png)

I have tried with the security policy allowing all traffic from all sources.  I have attempted connecting using a connection string in a basic dotnet app too, with same result.  If I remove the EC2 subnet from the security policy, SSMS cannot connect, so I am editing the correct policy and the settings seem correct, but I am clearly missing something and probably something so obvious it is staring me right in the face.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks more like an application error than a networking error. Can you connect to it using a different SQL client on your computer?

Comment: No, I can't connect using Azure Data Studio or standard Dotnet app on my computer.  EC2 instance on same VPC can connect, which along with the error does suggest network, but I can't see where the problem could be.

Comment: What if you run an SQL client like DBeaver -- that will test whether the problem is related to the network, and will hopefully give a better error message. Also pay attention to how long it takes before it fails -- a quick failure means the database rejected the connection while a delay before failure means the request never made it to the database so it would be a network configuration issue.

Comment: Another thing to check... You are presumably referencing the database via its DNS name. Try using `ping <DNS-NAME>` to see whether the DNS name resolves to an IP address. Ping itself won't work, but that isn't required -- it's just a handy way to see whether the name resolves to an IP address.

Comment: I have nslookup'd the host name and it resolves correctly (on the machine I am testing from), however, I have also tested using IP with the same result.  Error takes about 30s to generate, so typical of a network timeout.  I have successful connections from the same machine to three other RDS instances.

Comment: Did the IP address look like a Public IP address? Perhaps check the subnet in which it was deployed and make sure it is a public subnet? You could also (temporarily) open the security group to all IP addresses on that port (`0.0.0.0/0`), just to confirm that it isn't the Security Group that is blocking traffic.

Comment: The IP resolves to public IP and changing the security policy as suggested made no difference to public access.  I modified to confirm policy was affecting access overall by removing the EC2 subnet from the policy and then substituting with 0.0.0.0/0 - EC2 works with all traffic, public does not.  You can see why I am so stumped!!